# How to generate a control set per collection item by binding in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example, with a ObservableCollection of CustomClass, I want to have the following xaml.

```
<Label Content="Some bound property value of item 1 (CustomClass)" />
<TextBox Text="Also bound to some property of item 1" />

<Label Content="For item 2" />
<TextBox Text="For item 2" />
```

and so on. Consequently, this is viewer/editor for the collection.
Other controls may come, such as ComboBox to edit Enum-type property.
Of course when a collection item is removed, corresponding controls will be gone.

Although it would be easy if written in code-behind, I would like to try it in a xaml-way.

How would you do that? Or, is this approach useless?

Comment: Is [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Item Template and Binding to achieve the same. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is sample of this

Comment: It seems to work, maybe I need more exercises in .NET. Thank you.